# exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' NSHealthUpdateUsageDescritption

Tags: ios

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription must be set in the app's Info.plist in order to request write authorization.'

Info.plist has this entry

```
<key>NSHealthShareUsageDescription</key>
<string>some string value stating the reason</string>
```

Answer (score 27):

If you already added **NSHealthShareUsageDescription** but still get the exception.

It may be due to that the description is too **short**.

***Make sure the description is longer than 12 characters for all locales.***

e.g.

HelloHello -> Crash!!

HelloHelloHi -> OK

Comment: Great answer! Helped me

Comment: This drove me crazy

Answer (score 15):

The error wants `NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription` to be set.  Those are different keys as you can see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

- **NSHealthShareUsageDescription:** 
  Specifies a localized string that describes why the app wants to read HealthKit data. See NSHealthShareUsageDescription for details.
- **NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription:**
  Specifies a localized string that describes why the app wants to write data to the HealthKit store. See NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription for details.

Comment: This fixed it, I made a simple mistake not realizing there were two keys required one for read and the other to write. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for posting.  It seems this really should be a linker error... "The call 'requestAuthorizationToShareTypes' is being used but no 'NSHealthShareUsageDescription' key exists in the Info.plist". Crashing my app because I don't have a new build setting (who knew!) for iOS 10 is ... rude.

Answer (score 14):

If your app need use HealthKit, you should add read and write privileges in the Info.plist.

Write Privilege:

```
<key>NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription</key>
<string>some string value stating the reason</string>
```

Read Privilege:

```
<key>NSHealthShareUsageDescription</key>
<string>some string value stating the reason</string>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the image. Helped me a bunch!

Answer (score 7):

You must also add a key for NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription.

Add the following to your Info.plist:

```
<key>NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription</key>
<string>some string value stating the reason</string>
```

See [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) for details.