# Is it possible to read Apple Watch goals (move, step and stand) from HealthKit?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos

Is it possible to read Apple Watch move goal from HealthKit?

I can retrieve the Move value by using the Quantity Identifier  HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.activeEnergyBurned.  I could not find a similar identifier for the move goal.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Declared globally
var healthStore: HKHealthStore?

func prepareHealthKit() {
    guard HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() else {
        return
    }

    var readTypes = Set<HKObjectType>()
    readTypes.insert(HKObjectType.activitySummaryType())

    healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    healthStore!.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: readTypes) { (isSuccess, error) in
        /*
         Assuming you know the following steps:
         1. Start workout session: i.e. "HKWorkoutSession"
         2. Wait for delegate: i.e "workoutSession(_:didChangeTo:from:date:)"
         3. Start Query for Activity Summary in the delegate:
            i.e our "startQueryForActivitySummary()"
         */
    }
}
```

---

```
func startQueryForActivitySummary() {
    func createPredicate() -> NSPredicate? {
        let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent

        var dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day],
                                                     from: Date())
        dateComponents.calendar = calendar

        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForActivitySummary(with: dateComponents)
        return predicate
    }

    let queryPredicate = createPredicate()
    let query = HKActivitySummaryQuery(predicate: queryPredicate) { (query, summaries, error) -> Void in
        if let summaries = summaries {
            for summary in summaries {
                let activeEnergyBurned = summary.activeEnergyBurned.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.kilocalorie())
                let activeEnergyBurnedGoal = summary.activeEnergyBurnedGoal.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.kilocalorie())
                let activeEnergyBurnGoalPercent = round(activeEnergyBurned/activeEnergyBurnedGoal)

                print(activeEnergyBurnGoalPercent)
            }
        }
    }

    healthStore?.execute(query)
}
```

---

References:

- https://crunchybagel.com/accessing-activity-rings-data-from-healthkit
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkactivitysummary
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkactivitysummaryquery

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly for me after enabling health kit access using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863093/exception-nsinvalidargumentexception-nshealthupdateusagedescritption

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.  The move goal is accessible from `HKActivitySummary`.

You should request permission to read HKActivitySummaryType:

```
 let activitySummaryType = HKActivitySummaryType.activitySummaryType()
 let readDataTypes: Set<HKObjectType> = [activitySummaryType]
 healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: readDataTypes, completion: myCompletionHandler)
```

Then use `HKActivitySummaryQuery` to read the summary information

```
let query = HKActivitySummaryQuery(predicate: myPredicate) { (query, summaries, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        fatalError("*** Did not return a valid error object. ***")
    }

    if let activitySummaries = summaries {
        for summary in activitySummaries {
            print(summary.activeEnergyBurnedGoal)
            //do something with the summary here...
        }
    }
}
healthStore.execute(query)
```

Other activity summary data that is accessible from HKActivitySummary is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hkactivitysummary).

Comment: Your example is incomplete.  I copied your code into a new project and I couldn't get it work.